# Debian Stable upgrade to Debian Testing

Tags: apt

Ive followed the instructions here (https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) now i have the testing branch active and i pulled a lot of new stuff, so far so good.

Unfortunatelly, i somewhat now lost access to packages.

Example: sudo apt install tilix # <-- package name could not be found.

So i removed backports etc and replaced it with testing.

Why do i loose now access to lots of GNU tools + Extras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the state of various transitions, packages may not be available in Debian testing. Packages are also removed if they are buggy; this is why [`tilix`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/tilix) isn’t available.

One possible solution is to also configure the unstable repositories; this is what [the “Best practices for Testing users” section on the wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting#Best_practices_for_Testing_users) recommends. That won’t necessarily help with buggy packages, but that’s what you get for helping to develop the next release of Debian (thanks!).